# CFG for all string that don't end at ba?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

Here is my solution:

```
S-> Sab|Sbb|Saa  
S->aS  
S->bS  
S->ε
```

Is this solution right?

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about. If you just want general feedback, you are welcome to visit us in [chat].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wrong because you can use the fifth production, then the fourth production and finally the sixth production to make the string $ba$.

Just doing a little modification to your grammar you can obtain the right solution:

$S\to Xab|Xbb|Xaa|a|b|\epsilon$

$X\to aX|bX|\epsilon$

You can eliminate the epsilon production of $X$ as an exercise.

Comment: Please consider not to encourage undesirable posting behaviour.